# PyCharm и стандартные модули

Tags: python, python-3.x, ide, jetbrains

Моя PyCharm 2017.2 не видит некоторые стандартные модули Python (стоит 3.7.1), такие как math, sys и т.д.

Компиляция проходит нормально, ошибок нету, просто IDE говорит "No module named ..."

Читал топики на Stack, в Settings-Project Interpreter стоит коректная версия Python (она у меня одна), переставлять пробывал, папку config снес с папки с PyCharm.

**P.S.** Прошу сильно не ругать, понять столь, возможно, глупый вопрос, и простить :)

Comment: Пробовал указывать в интерпритаторе не системный питон, а виртуальное окружение?

Comment: Да, ето решило мою проблему.

Comment: Я только сел за Питон (первый вечер). Не мог бы ты подробней рассказать про виртуальное окружения? Есть ли отличия, и какие ?

Comment: Ето что-то типа Docker из коробки ?)

Comment: Не засоряет систему кучей сторонних библиотек и пакетов. Для каждого проекта, фактически своё рабочее окружение. Возможность выводить зависимости для проекта в файл. Прочитай в гугле python3 venv.

Comment: Cпасибо! Пока мне ето не нужно.

Answer (score 2):

Следуя инструкциям в [документации](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/creating-virtual-environment.html), установите новое виртуальное окружение.

1. Установите Python на ПК.
2. С **Ctrl+Alt+S** откройте **Settings/Preferences**.
3. Там выберете проект <имя проекта> | **Python Interprete**r. Кликните иконку коннфигурации - **(*)**, и далее **Add**.
4. И там выберете **Virtualenv Environment**.